# Using c# .NET 3.0 on a Windows XP machine, what is the most efficent way to record from multiple webcams?

Tags: c#, c#-3.0, windows-xp, directshow, webcam

I am trying to figure out what APIs to use to connect and record from a webcam. In al of my research, Google, I have found many OLD articles which discus Directshow and COM. I don't want to write code that is using an obsolete API.

Any direction with this is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DiectShow is still the best way to connect to Webcams (or other sources).
You can use [DirectShow.NET](http://directshownet.sourceforge.net/) which is a thin warpper arund DirectShow.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Vista, you can use the new [Media Foundation APIs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd317912(VS.85).aspx).  But, they are not available on XP, so DirectShow is the way to go.  The DirectShow.NET wrapper pointed to by Shay works great with C#.  Be sure to also download the [Samples](http://sourceforge.net/project/showfiles.php?group_id=136334&package_id=188409&release_id=529095), there are several capture samples worth checking out like PlayCap and CapWMV.

UberDemo wrote an article about another way of capturing using the Windows Media Encoder SDK with WPF in [this article.](http://blogs.msdn.com/uberdemo/archive/2008/03/27/capturing-a-webcam-stream-to-a-wmv-file-from-within-a-wpf-application.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

avicap32.dll I guess is the safest option due to its readily availability... http://channel9.msdn.com/forums/TechOff/93476-Programatically-Using-A-Webcam-In-C has the PInvoke code you will be needing.

http://codeplex.com/touchless is an interesting related project!